# Node-red temperature sensor with function node and relay

Tags: javascript, node-red, home-automation

I want to use a DS18b20 probe connected to Raspberri Pi to control by aircon.
I get the relay to switch on and off at the correct temperatures I want.
The next step is where I am struggling...
My requirements:
Switch aircon off <= 20 (this works)
Switch aircon on >= 25 (this works)
when the aircon switches on above 25...keep the aircon on until 20 is reached, then switch off (this I can't get working)
when the aircon switches off, wait for 10min {to protect the motor} (This I can't get working)

I have tried using a function node with the following code:

[image: image of code]

Any help here it be greatly appreciated...I have tried doing the same with switch and change nodes, but I can;t get the delay portion working then or get it to stay on to cool down till 20.

Comment: Are you able to provide the code that isn't working? Images are not very useful at all. Besides, the image you provided doesn't seem to contain all the code necessary to answer your question - and it also has syntax errors.

Comment: If the code in the image is all you have, then have a think about each of the conditions. The first three conditions should be logical conjunctions (`&&`), rather than disjunctions (`||`). The `while` condition is not syntactically correct. `(...)(...)` should be written as `(... && ...)`.

Comment: You are probably going to need to save state in the context to get this working properly, but you should also look at the trigger node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in order to get this working you need flow context variables to store the state.  I have created below example flow for your problem which makes use of the following 2 context variables:

- **aircon_is_on** : is a boolean indicating if the aircon is currently switched on or off.
- **aircon_last_switch_tms** : is a timestamp (expressed in number of milli seconds since 1970) of the last time the aircon has been switch on or off.

[image]

The details of the flow you can find here below.

```
[{"id":"cc99810d.fdcb8","type":"tab","label":"Flow 1","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"16703345.888dcd","type":"inject","z":"cc99810d.fdcb8","name":"initialisation at startup","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":true,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":180,"y":80,"wires":[["97135670.acdd88"]]},{"id":"97135670.acdd88","type":"change","z":"cc99810d.fdcb8","name":"initialize flow variables","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"aircon_is_on","pt":"flow","to":"false","tot":"bool"},{"t":"set","p":"aircon_last_switch_tms","pt":"flow","to":"0","tot":"jsonata"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":440,"y":80,"wires":[[]]},{"id":"3f26e3af.245a1c","type":"inject","z":"cc99810d.fdcb8","name":"","topic":"","payload":"19","payloadType":"num","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":130,"y":200,"wires":[["cd981b11.6bac88"]]},{"id":"d7ffb888.3cd648","type":"comment","z":"cc99810d.fdcb8","name":"inject nodes simulating the DS18b20 sensor output","info":"","x":210,"y":140,"wires":[]},{"id":"d0544032.848e","type":"inject","z":"cc99810d.fdcb8","name":"","topic":"","payload":"20","payloadType":"num","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":130,"y":240,"wires":[["cd981b11.6bac88"]]},{"id":"995c2849.57d9f8","type":"inject","z":"cc99810d.fdcb8","name":"","topic":"","payload":"21","payloadType":"num","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":130,"y":280,"wires":[["cd981b11.6bac88"]]},{"id":"f6cee931.a62e78","type":"inject","z":"cc99810d.fdcb8","name":"","topic":"","payload":"24","payloadType":"num","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":130,"y":320,"wires":[["cd981b11.6bac88"]]},{"id":"3dcf7adb.db0d66","type":"inject","z":"cc99810d.fdcb8","name":"","topic":"","payload":"25","payloadType":"num","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":130,"y":360,"wires":[["cd981b11.6bac88"]]},{"id":"76d055f9.3878dc","type":"inject","z":"cc99810d.fdcb8","name":"","topic":"","payload":"26","payloadType":"num","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":130,"y":400,"wires":[["cd981b11.6bac88"]]},{"id":"7698406b.1ca73","type":"change","z":"cc99810d.fdcb8","name":"set flow context and payload to switch off aircon","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"aircon_is_on","pt":"flow","to":"false","tot":"bool"},{"t":"set","p":"aircon_last_switch_tms","pt":"flow","to":"","tot":"date"},{"t":"set","p":"payload","pt":"msg","to":"false","tot":"bool"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":1060,"y":220,"wires":[["7d3fbf47.1bc7a"]]},{"id":"cd981b11.6bac88","type":"switch","z":"cc99810d.fdcb8","name":"aircon is on ?","property":"aircon_is_on","propertyType":"flow","rules":[{"t":"true"},{"t":"false"}],"checkall":"true","repair":false,"outputs":2,"x":330,"y":300,"wires":[["ea9a6fa9.67ae5"],["fc9c4632.967d78"]]},{"id":"ea9a6fa9.67ae5","type":"switch","z":"cc99810d.fdcb8","name":"temp <= 20 ?","property":"payload","propertyType":"msg","rules":[{"t":"lte","v":"20","vt":"num"}],"checkall":"true","repair":false,"outputs":1,"x":510,"y":220,"wires":[["7698406b.1ca73"]]},{"id":"7d3fbf47.1bc7a","type":"debug","z":"cc99810d.fdcb8","name":"aircon command to switch it on / off","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"payload","x":1400,"y":280,"wires":[]},{"id":"fc9c4632.967d78","type":"switch","z":"cc99810d.fdcb8","name":"temp >= 25 ?","property":"payload","propertyType":"msg","rules":[{"t":"gte","v":"25","vt":"num"}],"checkall":"true","repair":false,"outputs":1,"x":510,"y":320,"wires":[["78c00f1f.7f943"]]},{"id":"78c00f1f.7f943","type":"switch","z":"cc99810d.fdcb8","name":"switch on / off more than 10 minutes ago ?","property":"($toMillis($now())-$flowContext(\"aircon_last_switch_tms\")) > (10*60*1000)","propertyType":"jsonata","rules":[{"t":"true"}],"checkall":"true","repair":false,"outputs":1,"x":700,"y":380,"wires":[["c5c075a6.a039b8"]]},{"id":"c5c075a6.a039b8","type":"change","z":"cc99810d.fdcb8","name":"set flow context and payload to switch off aircon","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"aircon_is_on","pt":"flow","to":"true","tot":"bool"},{"t":"set","p":"aircon_last_switch_tms","pt":"flow","to":"","tot":"date"},{"t":"set","p":"payload","pt":"msg","to":"true","tot":"bool"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":1080,"y":380,"wires":[["7d3fbf47.1bc7a"]]},{"id":"a8acfa78.442cd8","type":"debug","z":"cc99810d.fdcb8","name":"flow.aircon_last_switch_tms  (in milli seconds since 1970)","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"payload","x":730,"y":540,"wires":[]},{"id":"e6dec5ed.6e6d78","type":"inject","z":"cc99810d.fdcb8","name":"flow.aircon_last_switch_tms","topic":"","payload":"aircon_last_switch_tms","payloadType":"flow","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":180,"y":540,"wires":[["a8acfa78.442cd8","b8c55cf8.7f1fe"]]},{"id":"2a2df95.069e206","type":"debug","z":"cc99810d.fdcb8","name":"flow.aircon_last_switch_tms","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"payload","x":640,"y":600,"wires":[]},{"id":"b8c55cf8.7f1fe","type":"change","z":"cc99810d.fdcb8","name":"$fromMillis(payload)","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"payload","pt":"msg","to":"$fromMillis(payload)","tot":"jsonata"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":360,"y":600,"wires":[["2a2df95.069e206"]]},{"id":"ff677399.2c529","type":"comment","z":"cc99810d.fdcb8","name":"test nodes to check the aircon flow context variables","info":"","x":227,"y":462,"wires":[]},{"id":"4a49b01b.1db3","type":"inject","z":"cc99810d.fdcb8","name":"","topic":"","payload":"aircon_is_on","payloadType":"flow","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":169,"y":499,"wires":[["2497d1be.1155ce"]]},{"id":"2497d1be.1155ce","type":"debug","z":"cc99810d.fdcb8","name":"flow.aircon_is_on","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"payload","x":610,"y":500,"wires":[]},{"id":"14796044.a8c56","type":"comment","z":"cc99810d.fdcb8","name":"output to switch on /off aircon","info":"","x":1360,"y":100,"wires":[]},{"id":"3411ff23.37aa1","type":"comment","z":"cc99810d.fdcb8","name":"aircon flow context variables","info":"This flow makes use of 2 flow context variables:\n1. *aircon_is_on* : is a boolean indicating if the aircon is currently switched on or off.\n2. *aircon_last_switch_tms* : is a timestamp (expressed in number of milli seconds since 1970) of the last time the aircon has been switch on or off.","x":453,"y":26,"wires":[]}]
```

kr
Jan

Comment: I have made a little typo in one of the flow names (not in the flow codes).  As you can see there are 2 flows with name _"set flow context and payload to switch off aircon"_.  This is not correct.  The lower flow should get name _"set flow context and payload to switch **on** aircon"_

Comment: Hi Jan, thanl you very much. You showed me I have a lot to learn ;)

Comment: { code: "T1006", stack: "Error↵ at applyInner (/usr/…", position: 11, token: "toMillis", message: "Attempted to invoke a non-func…" }red/node_modules/jsonata/jsonata.js:1580:27)\n at next (native)","position":11,"token":"toMillis","message":"Attempted to invoke a non-function"} ....  this is at the "switch on / off more than 10 minutes ago ?" switch node

Comment: Apparently the jsonata function `toMillis()` used in my jsonata expression is not known in your node-red installation.  So I think you are using a bit older version of node-red  than I am.  1/ Can you try to upgrade node-red and check if this fixed the error ?
2/ Did you also get an error when triggering the bottom flow `flow.aircon_last_switch_tms` which prints the `flow.aircon_last_switch_tms` in the debug window ?
3/ Of course instead of using a jsonata expression to check that the switching on/off happened more than 10 minutes ago_ , you can also do this in javascript in a function node.

Comment: Thank you very much! Got it working after the update